# Email in Django not sending

Tags: django, django-views, django-email

I'm trying to send an email with Gmail SMTP, all my email settings are correct but the email is not send and I receive no exceptions.
I'm pulling my values from an HTML form. Also, I noticed when I try sending a mail from the shell terminal, it actually sends, but not on the app itself.

**email settings**

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', default=True, cast=bool)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def send_mail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name= request.POST["name"]
        gender= request.POST["gender"]
        contact_addr= request.POST["contact_addr"]

        msg = 'Hello', name


        send_mail(
            "Subject",
            msg,
            'sender@gmail.com',
            ["receiver@gmail.com"],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

        return render(request, "main.html", {'name':name})
    else:
        return render(request, "main.html", {})
```

**html template**

```html
<form
        action="{% url 'app:success' %}"
        method="POST"
      >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input
            name="name"
            id="name"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="gender">Gender</label>
          <input
            name="gender"
            id="gender"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="contact">Contact</label>
          
          <input
            name="contact"
            id="contact"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <input type="submit" value="send" />
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your setup?

Comment: Yes please send a snippet of your settings.py and your view. Don't show the info like password as that should be kept secret

Comment: Added the snippet already

Comment: Assign a variable to 'send_mail' like: 
xyz = send_mail(....). Also dont name your view the same as a method. It can get confusing

Comment: ok... then, how do i call the variable for it to send the mail?

Comment: Also I'm assuming that the email addresses you're using are real ones, not receiver and sender right?

Comment: You're probably right that we dont have to assign a variable, however that is what I have done in my website.

Comment: If you're trying to say 'hello name' then it would be 
msg = 'hello ' + name or 
msg = f'hello {name}'

Comment: yh, tried it(the variable stuff), same result,

Comment: How are you submitting the form and is the request method definitely "POST"? Rename your view to something other than "send_mail"

Comment: `msg = 'Hello', name` -- change this to `msg = f'Hello {name}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I noticed for the mail to send, the form action has to return to itself(i don't know why, but that is how it's sending). So `<form action="{% url 'app:success' %}" method="POST">` become `<form action="{% url 'app:send_mail' %}" method="POST">`

Answer (score 0):

- You're not providing `email` appropriately to Django for send mail.
- Change the name of view.
- You're not providing anything that Django knows if email is sent or Not.

You should create a **form** (maybe for test it). (You can also do it without form) :-

forms.py

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

```
from .forms import EmailForm
 
def sending_email_django(request):

    sent = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)

        subject = f" This is email via Django."\
        message = f" Is email is receiving ? "\

        send_mail(subject, message, 'sender_host_email@gmail.com',
                   ['receiver_host_email@gmail.com'])

        sent = True # Email is sent

    else:
        form = EmailForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'send_email_page.html', context)
```

> Don't forget to import the EmailForm in view.

**Note :-**

- I am not saving the form in `database`.
- If you want to send email to Django's registered user then you have to specify the email of `receiver` at the place of `[receiver_host_email@gmail.com]` like `[request.user.email]`.

Comment: I'm not using a Django form, rather an HTML contact form and also i have the changed the name of the view to something else, still the same result.

Comment: Did you `test` it with `form` ?

Comment: Yes , I did. Everything works perfectly but no mail is sent, and I received no error.

Comment: I've edited the question, you can check the template. @PrOgRaMmEr